# What kind of information can I get out of an "input" event? Is there a better way of tracking text changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, algorithm, events

I am trying to capture changes to a text area and decipher what changes were made to the text.

I am doing this to somewhat copy the behavior of a 'tag-able' editor such as the one on Facebook - where you can 'tag' your friend or a public page.

My plan is to track the indexes of 'tagged words' in the string input (with some object containing data about the placement of the 'tagged words'). So this means that whenever a word/phrase is typed/pasted into the textarea, I want to know exactly what changed in the text to update the indexes of the 'tagged words'.

I ran into an event that seems to fit my need:

`textAreaEl.bind("input", function (e) {});`

To proceed with this, I want to be able to figure out what exactly changed in the text to trigger this event .. from the 'e' object.

Is there a way to decipher what actually happened to the text before and after this event triggered? I took a stab at it, but came up empty. (e.which was even undefined after I entered something from the keyboard).

Also, is there a better way of tracking a string of characters in a larger string?

Comment: `$('input').on('change keydown keypress keyup mousedown click mouseup', function(event){console.log(event)}) `? jquery

Comment: How would I know which event actually fired from the event object?

Comment: its in the event [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxpx1yts/16/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the position (indexed at 0) of a string inside of another string using `string.indexOf()`.

To find the complete text input of a text area or input, use `element.value`.

To detect when a textarea is modified, you can play around with `addEventListener`.

If you want to modify the contents of the textarea by changing coloration etc of its contents, that's much more difficult and I would even recommend using a `div` element with `contenteditable` instead.

Some references:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Edit: Read your question a bit more slowly, and seems like what you're doing is you're trying to see if you can detect what changes were made. However, the purpose of this seems like you want to see what tags were added, and therefore this becomes a x/y misconception.

You don't need to exactly check what changes were made, all you need to do is check the input again every time they press a new key (or even only check for the `#` key). To explicitly find the difference between before and after is not needed.

Comment: I thought about using indexof until I thought about situations where you can copy/paste identical words multiple times and it could get messy.

Comment: I also fooled around with contenteditable, which solves this problem about tracking the special phrases, but we decided to stick with a text area because that opened a lot of other cans of worms

Comment: About your problem with indexOf, if you are worried about identical words you can run a loop that repeats every time you find the string in question, deletes the string from future loops, then runs again. This ensures that it will keep rechecking the string until all relevant tags are found.

Comment: The problem is not finding the initial indexes of the 'tagged words'. It's with trying to locate them after a couple edits are made (input added before and after the text). To be able to do that, I would need to keep track of what happens to the text, no?

Comment: Another option is using `regex`. You can use `String.search(/helloworld/g)` and use a regex filter to find all the locations in which there is a tag. You can then use this to parse the data.

Comment: Is there something limiting you from simply running the text again after edits are made? Every time you make an edit, forget what you knew about the text before, run it through as if it was new. It shouldn't change much.

Comment: an issue with using regex, is that tags on facebook are just normal words. There is no special '@' or '#' that proceeds them. Also, there can be uses of '@' and '#' that are actually meant to be part of the text (and not a special tag)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111265/discussion-between-daemonofthewest-and-sherman-s).